# Controlling rviz via rosservice

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use rviz as a viewer for an external path planning application. In the application, controlled by python, I have robots and obstacles. Robots are downloaded via urdf files by python commands. In my current understanding of rviz, to visualize a robot, I need to click on the "Add" button to add a robot. Is it possible to add a robot only by python commands via a ros service for instance ?

`rosservice call rviz add_robot ${robot_name}_description`

Same question for collada or vrml meshes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122961/controlling-rviz-via-rosservice/) by [florent-lamiraux](https://answers.ros.org/users/5734/florent-lamiraux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz uses the system robot_description parameter. If you want to visualize another robot for a path planning application I recommend looking at the MoveIt rviz plugins as examples.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1